# How to open $uibModal from within modal Controller?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
app.controller('addEmployeeCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, newEmployee){
  $scope.addNewVehicle=function(){
    // I want to open a new modal here
  };    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to open a second modal in much the same way as you opened the first...

Inject the `$uibModal` service into `addEmployeeCtrl` and make a call to `$uibModal.open()` passing in another modal configuration object.

```
app.controller('addEmployeeCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $uibModal, newEmployee){

  $scope.addNewVehicle = function(){

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'addVehicle.html',
      controller: 'addVehicleCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'vehicleVm'
      // Any other modal config properties here
    }

    modalInstance.result.then(closedCallback, dismissedCallback);

    function closedCallback(){
      // Do something when the modal is closed
    }

    function dismissedCallback(){
      // Do something when the modal is dismissed
    }
  };  
});
```

Comment: I think there is an error in the code, maybe due to some updates: `modalInstance.then` should be `modalInstance.result.then`